# RelativeLayout widgets width larger that RelativeLayout width

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a RelativeLayout that is the top bar of an AppWidget.
It contains 3 ImageViews with fixed witdh and 1 TextView, depending on TextView text or Widget size the RelativeLayout width can be smaller than the sum of single widget, in this case textview and imageview overlay one over the other. I would like to avoid it, an accettable solution could be also to hide textview if there is no space.

How can I do it?

```
    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_top"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/iv_logo"
                android:layout_width="32dip"
                android:layout_height="32dip"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"
                android:contentDescription="@string/logo"  /> 

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tv_title"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_title"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/iv_logo" />

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/iv_new"
                android:layout_width="32dip"
                android:layout_height="32dip"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv_refresh"
                android:src="@drawable/neww"
                android:contentDescription="@string/neww"  />

            <ImageView 
                android:id="@+id/iv_refresh"
                android:layout_width="32dip"
                android:layout_height="32dip"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:src="@drawable/refresh"
                android:contentDescription="@string/refresh"  />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: do it programatically.. it dont think you can set it to automatically do what you want

Comment: The problem is that it is part of an AppWidget, any way I have solved using a LinearLayout insted of the RelativeLayout and using layout_weight

Comment: better close the question then :)

Answer (score 0):

set width of texvView a fixed value and Wrap_content height. I hope this will fix it.